# finding expectation of a product of random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a geometric random variable with probability of succes $p$. I want to show that for $r = 2,3,4,... $, we have

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ X(X-1)...(X-r+1) \} = \frac{ r! p^r}{(1-p)^r } $$

Since $1-p \leq 1$, I start with

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ( 1 -p)^k = \frac{1}{p }$$

and differentiate $r$ times to obtain

$$ \sum k(k-1)...(k-r+1) \frac{(1-p)^k}{(1-p)^r} = \frac{ (-1)^r r!}{p^r}$$

and so

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ X(X-1)...(X-r+1) \} = \frac{ r! p^r}{(1-p)^r }  = \sum_k k(k-1)...(k-r+1)p (1-p)^k = \frac{(-1)^r r! (1-p)^r p}{p^r}$$

which looks different to what the expected value should be according to the book. where am I wrong?

Comment: Google:  "factorial moment generating function"

Comment: Those who asked the exercise define geometric distribution using the weights $(1-p)p^{k}$, not $p(1-p)^k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability of **success** on any one trial, and let $Y$ be the number of successes until the first failure. Then for $k=0,1,2,\dots$ we have $\Pr(Y=k)=p^k (1-p)$. We want $E[Y(Y-1)\cdots (Y-r+1)]$. This is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\cdots (k-r+1) p^k(1-p).$$
We use your strategy, starting from
$$\sum_0^\infty p^k=\frac{1}{1-p},$$
and differentiating $r$ times. We get
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\cdots (k-r+1) p^{k-r}=\frac{r!}{(1-p)^{r+1}}.$$
Multiply by $(1-p)p^r$. We get
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\cdots (k-r+1) p^k(1-p)=\frac{r!p^r}{(1-p)^r}.$$
Note that the argument also works for $r=1$.

**Remark:** There are two slightly different definitions of geometric distribution. In one of them, more common in elementary courses, we count the number of *trials*. In the other, we count the number of "successes" until the first failure (or failures until the first success).